# How do I find the last <div class> in an HTML File with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

According to the documentation for [SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (under the tab “How to modify HTML Elements”), this code finds the first instance of `<div class="hello">`:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class="hello">Hello</div><div class="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div[class=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; // Output: <div class="hello">foo</div><div class="world">World</div>
```

What if I want to insert 'foo' into the *last* instance of `<div class="hello">`, assuming that the HTML code has a lot of instances of `<div class="hello">`.

What should replace the `0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, since

```
// Find all anchors, returns a array of element objects
$ret = $html->find('whatever');
```

returns an `array` holding all the `<whatever>` elements, you can fetch the last element with PHP's regular array functions, e.g. with [`end`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
$last = end($ret);
```

If SimpleHtmlDom fully implements [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo) for querying, you can also modify your query to use

```
:last-of-type
```

to only find the last sibling in returned nodelist.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual:

```
// Find lastest anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
$ret = $html->find('a', -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

*lastChild* property returns the last child object of an element.

EDIT:
not JQuery obviously :)
See the W3C selector reference instead: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo

Comment: It's not JQuery selectors. It's just selectors. That's a W3C spec.

Comment: Umm, there's still a lastChild property in DOM so it's selectable anyway. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp
Don't get what the -1 is for.

Comment: @crowicked: Probably for ignoring the tags and the link to _exactly_ what the OP is using, then assuming jQuery for some reason. *lastChild* is a good shout, though.

Comment: I didnt dv, but if you want to link to proper specs, use http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors. w3schools is known for poor and often false material. Also, w3schools is not affiliated with w3c.

Comment: The JQuery part was (wrongly, my bad) just an addition to my answer. It doesn't make it wrong, as it refers to the DOM documentation. So that's ignorance, too. But hey, I gotta get a minus sometimes.

Comment: Like I said, I didnt dv, but as a general tip: if you know there is something wrong in your answer, correct it. This gives people the chance to lift the dv again. It's no guarantee they do, but it improves your chances.

Comment: Note that your update still suggests the wrong selector though. last-child does what it says, while the OP is looking for the last sibling, so that would be http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo

Answer (score -2):

The original post question was "What should replace the 0?"

Answer: -1